# Fluent bit larger log from docker

Tags: docker, fluent-bit

I want to read logs from stdout where the Java app logs. Logs are getting by forward as parser I used docker. Problem is that some of the logs is huge, especially where is some stack trace. The log is split into many logs and problem is that the log is visible even exception message. Configuration is going to run on Kubernetes but for the test I use docker.

```
[INPUT]
   Name              forward
   Listen            0.0.0.0
   Port              24224
   

[FILTER]
    name             parser
    match            *
    key_name         log
    parser           docker

[OUTPUT]
    Name   stdout
    Match  *
```

I tried to contact logs but it doesn't work using this configuration: https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/filters/multiline-stacktrace#docker-partial-message-use-case

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Surely, you want the exception message be be visible in the log, right?

Comment: Exception message is split to next log, what does mean stack trace is in 10 or more separated logs

Answer (score 0):

This setup works for me:

fluent-bit.conf

```
[SERVICE]
  flush                 1
  log_level             info
  parsers_file          parsers_multiline.conf

[INPUT]
  name                  tail
  refresh_interval      5
  path                  /var/log/*.log
  read_from_head        true

[FILTER]
  name                  multiline
  match                 *
  multiline.key_content log
  multiline.parser      go, multiline-regex-test

[OUTPUT]
  Name http
  Match *
  Host data-prepper
  Port 2021
  URI /log/ingest
```

parsers_multiline.conf

```
[MULTILINE_PARSER]
    name          multiline-regex-test
    type          regex
    flush_timeout 1000
    rule      "start_state"   "/^2022.*/"  "cont"
    rule      "cont"          "/^(\D{4})/"                     "cont"
```

sources:

- https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/administration/configuring-fluent-bit/multiline-parsing
- https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/filters/multiline-stacktrace